# SQL Query to read a text file and display only selected contents from that

Tags: sql-server

I am working on something which requires me to run an sql query to read a text file from a path but it has to display only few contents based on my conditions/requirements. I have read about using ROWSET/BULK copy but it copies the entire file but I need only certain data from the file.

Ex:

> ```
> Line 1 - Hello, Good Morning.  
> Line 2 - Have a great day ahead.  
> Line 3 - Phone Number : 1112223333 and so on.
> ```

So, if I read this file and give the condition as "1112223333", it should display only the lines consisting of "1112223333".

NOTE: It should display the entire line of the matched case/condition

Is it possible to achieve this using an sql query? If so then please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you reading the lines into a table? If so, just use `[LineColumn] LIKE '%1112223333%'` as a predicate in the `WHERE` clause to select rows that include that text.

Comment: @Diado I am inserting into a table but the problem is I am reading from a .txt file.
The .txt file has normal paragraphs not the copy of rowset from the db.
Here's few rows of the file that I want to be inserted
:      Processing Time: 8.65
  Control Date = 2018-08-16 06:46:29

Input File Name:       \\.....\check.txt


Provider:        TEST
Format Class:    TEST
...... and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're trying to do doesn't work with `ROWSET`. There is no way to apply a filter at read time.  You're stuck with reading in the entire table.  You can of course read into a temp table, then delete the rows. This will give you the desired end result, but you have to take the hit on reading in the entire table.

You may be able to generate a script to filter the file server side and trigger that with `xp_cmdshell` but you'd still need to take the performance hit somewhere. While this would be lower load on the SQL server, you'd just be pushing the processing elsewhere, and you'd still have to wait for the processing to happen before you could read the file.  May be worth doing if the file is on a separate server and network traffic is an issue. If the file is on the same server, unless SQL is completely bogged down, I can't see an advantage to this.

Comment: This could work but since I am reading from a .txt file which has say n number of lines, can I insert the read data from the file line by line into separate rows? i.e., I want 1st line of the .txt file to be inserted into 1st row, 2nd line into 2nd row and so on. If this is possible, can you please help me with a query for the same since I am able to insert it as a single row only but not into multiple rows..

Comment: I have experimented with OPENROWSET but the problem is when I insert the data into a temp table it'll be inserted as a single row because of which, even when I include a where clause, it'll be applied on the entire line..

Comment: Hi mate. Sounds like you've got an issue with the row terminator.  If you stipulate the row terminator it should go in row by row.

Comment: Yep, there was an issue with Row Terminator. It's working as expected. Thanks for the help..:)